# What's the difference between "Int32" and "google.protobuf.Int32Value"?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a proto3 message on a legacy C# codebase, and I noticed that if I replace

```
import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";
import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

message Foo {
    google.protobuf.Int32Value blah = 1;
}
```

with:

```
message Foo {
    int32 blah = 1;
}
```

the parser still works, but `blah` receives `0` instead of the proper value.

Why did it happen? Should `int32` not be equivalent to `google.protobuf.Int32Value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int32 is a built-in type that represents a 32-bit signed integer. It is defined in the System namespace, and you can use it like this:

```
int x = 5;
```

On the other hand, google.protobuf.Int32Value is a class defined in the Google Protocol Buffers library. This library provides a way to serialize structured data, such as messages or objects, in a compact binary format that is both efficient and easy to work with.

Int32Value is a wrapper class that allows you to use a 32-bit integer value as a message field in a Protocol Buffers message. You would use it like this:

```
google.protobuf.Int32Value x = 5;
```

The main difference between Int32 and Int32Value is that the latter is a class, while the former is a built-in type. This means that Int32Value has additional functionality, such as the ability to be used as a field in a Protocol Buffers message, whereas Int32 does not have this capability.

Answer (score 7):

`Int32Value` is a wrapper message type defined in [wrappers.proto](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/wrappers.proto). As far as I know, it was used to represent *"possibly missing int32"* in a portable manner, as all languages don't have nullable types. For normal fields, the `proto3` syntax automatically sets missing integers to have value zero.

Internally `Int32Value` is encoded as a submessage, so replacing it with a `int32` field will break message type compatibility.

In protobuf version 3.15, released in 2021, the [proto3 syntax also added support for optional fields](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#specifying_field_rules). As such I don't see any reason to use `Int32Value` for new projects anymore, though it will remain supported for compatibility with old message types.

Even the proto3 optional fields are [not exposed as native nullable types](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9083), and require separate use of `.HasField()` calls.

Comment: Is `optional` a real replacement for the wrapper types? It's usage in c# is problematic in terms of DX. Here is my question on `optional` vs wrapper types https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77789245/why-when-use-optional-over-google-protobuf-wrappers-proto-in-c-sharp-with-nu