# Why/when use `optional` over `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto` in C# with nullable fields?

Tags: c#, .net-core, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-c#

Why/when use `optional` over `google/protobuf/wrappers.proto` in C# when need to map nullable fields?

Let's say I have the following proto file:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

service Calculator {
  rpc SumWrapper (SumWrapperRequest) returns (SumResponse);
  rpc SumOptional (SumOptionalRequest) returns (SumResponse);
}

message SumOptionalRequest {
  optional int64  X = 1;
  optional int64  Y = 2;
}

message SumResponse {
  int64 Answer = 1;
}

message SumWrapperRequest {
  google.protobuf.Int64Value X = 1;
  google.protobuf.Int64Value Y = 2;
}
```

With `SumWrapper`, the request fields are mapped to `long?`, so I can use the direct comparison to null like: `request.X == null` in the implementation. Also, it allows me to assign `long?` values to the request in the client code like:

```cs
long? x = null;
long? y = 2;

var sumWrapperRequest = new SumWrapperRequest { X = x, Y = y };
```

Now, with the `SumOptionalRequest` the ergonomics of using the generated code are way worse. I have to use `request.HasX` to check for null, and other devs can forget to use it and will get the default value (`0` in case of int64), and finally, there is no way to initialize and set the nullable value in a single expression, and instead need to do it like this:

```cs
long? x = null;
long? y = 2;

var sumRequest = new SumOptionalRequest();
if (x.HasValue)
{
    sumRequest.X = x.Value;
}
```

However, `optional` was added on purpose to the specification, so I wonder when and why it makes sense to use it with nullable fields?

Comment: I suspect (!) that you should use `optional` in preference to the wrapper types now that `optional` has been returned to `proto3`.  The wrappers exist, in part, because `optional` was not initially present in `proto3` and a way was needed to detect absence vs. default values. It's important to not only consider the impact on .NET stubs too for two reasons. First, protobuf is cross-platform and stubs in other langauges will implement this behavior differently (Rust's tonic generates the same implementation, for example). Second, the .NET plugin could change how the code is generated.

Comment: @IvanD
I'm in the same situation right now. 
The protobuf documentation says to use `optional` and the Microsoft documentation says to use the `wrappers`.
For C# the `wrappers` are of course easier to work with.
How did you decide and why?

Comment: If `optional` is used and no value is set, then this field is not serialized according to protobuf documentation (https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#field-labels)

Comment: I use wrappers, working with `optional` is pain.

Answer (score 0):

Please the @DazWilkin comment. Also note that `optional` better maps on semantics of other programming languages.